# Time to Temperature Calculation

Tags: c#, math, time

This might not be the correct place for this, so apologies in advance if it isn't.

My situation - I need to come up with a simple formula/method of giving it an hour E.g. 13, 15, 01 etc, and based on that number, the method will return the 'approx' temperature for that particular time.

This is very approximate and it will not use weather data or anything like that, it will just take the hour of the day and return a value between say -6 deg C > 35 deg C. (very extreme weather, but you get the idea.)

This is the sort of examples I would like to know how to do:

[image: TimevsTemp]

Just as a note, I COULD use an ugly array of 24 items, each referencing the temp for that hour, but this needs to be float based - e.g. 19.76 should return 9.25 deg...

Another note: I don't want a complete solution - I'm a confident programmer in various languages, but the maths have really stumped me on this. I've tried various methods on paper using TimeToPeak (the peak hour being 1pm or around there) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: Write a class which will have the array of 24 elements, in which you'll have the hourly values. Add a function which takes float. Take the whole number and the fraction from it, and (dependent on distribution you need) select the correct temperature. I don't see anything complicated about it ;)

Comment: Shouldn't 19.76 return around 9.25 ?

Comment: @ElRonnoco - Yes, I was giving a (very poor) approximation.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Following your comment, here is a function that provides a sinusoidal distribution with various useful optional parameters.

```
private static double SinDistribution(
    double value,
    double lowToHighMeanPoint = 0.0,
    double length = 10.0,
    double low = -1.0,
    double high = 1.0)
{
    var amplitude = (high - low) / 2;
    var mean = low + amplitude;
    return mean + (amplitude * Math.Sin(
        (((value - lowToHighMeanPoint) % length) / length) * 2 * Math.PI));
}
```

You could use it like this, to get the results you desired.

```
for (double i = 0.0; i < 24.0; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, SinDistribution(i, 6.5, 24.0, -6.0, 35.0));
}
```

This obviously discounts environmental factors and assumes the day is an equinox but I think it answers the question.

---

So,

```
double EstimatedTemperature(double hour, double[] distribution)
{
    var low = Math.Floor(hour);
    var lowIndex = (int)low;
    var highIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(hour);

    if (highIndex > distribution.Count - 1)
    {
       highIndex = 0;
    }

    if (lowIndex < 0)
    {
        lowIndex = distribution.Count - 1;
    }  

    var lowValue = distribution.ElementAt(lowIndex);
    var highValue = distribution.ElementAt(highIndex);

    return lowValue + ((hour - low) * (highValue - lowValue));
}
```

assuming a rather simplistic linear transition between each point in the distibution. You'll get erroneous results if the hour is mapped to elements that are not present in the distribution.

Comment: This does not however solve the issue of having an array of 24 values for the temperatures.

Comment: This is a simple solution, and would probably work well - but I don't want to use an array of values. This is for a game, and I dont want to keep having to alter an array of values when the player walks around different "regions" with different max and mins.

Thanks anyway, this is a great solution.

Comment: I added a short example of how you can do this with simple tests before return.

Comment: @brighterdean, edited to provide somthing like what you are looking for.

Comment: @brighterdean, if your virtual world has just one sun you could look at this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary data points, I would go with one of the other linear interpolation solutions that have been provided.

However, this particular set of data is generated by a [triangle wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave):

```
temp = 45*Math.Abs(2*((t-1)/24-Math.Floor((t-1)/24+.5)))-10;
```

Comment: Damn, this answer was so small, I nearly missed it. Having that formula is great, but is there any chance someone could actually explain the maths behind it?

Comment: Sad but true. If you take the easy way out where someone spoons out the solution you will never advance your knowledge one iota.

Comment: So is this answer suitable for arbitrary data interpolation as the OP suggests his data is (eg temperatures)??

Comment: @brighterdean - Brief explanation of the math:  Start with the Wikipedia link.  Then, the particular constants for this problem: 45: the difference between your max and min temps; 24: the period of the wave (the cycle repeats every 24 hours); -10: because your lowest value is -10, not 0; (t-1) instead of t: because your min values occurs at t==1, not t==0.

Comment: @ElRonnoco - "For arbitrary data points, I would go with one of the other linear interpolation solutions that have been provided.".

Comment: @MichaelKaras - You'll find many answers on this site that provide the source code for a complete solution, rather than just giving a broad outline of how to tackle the problem.  In this case, if one has not had experience with triangle waves, the derivation is not obvious - not much point in trying to just guide the OP to derive the equation.

Comment: @mbeckish - But this is what the OP said in his original question: "Another note: I don't want a complete solution - I'm a confident programmer in various languages, but the maths have really stumped me on this. I've tried various methods on paper using TimeToPeak (the peak hour being 1pm or around there) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated at this point."

Comment: @MichaelKaras - I guess the OP didn't anticipate that in this case the math IS the entire solution.

Comment: @mbeckish You're correct. I maybe should have asked this on a math Q&A site rather than a coding site. As code, this is a beautiful answer - it does precisely what I want in one line, however, I wanted more of an explanation of HOW to do what I wanted. The wiki page is pretty helpful and I have more of an understanding of what it is doing now, so thanks for all your help.

Comment: @brighterdean - In that case, here's a little more explanation: 1) Start with the equation of a line with the slope matching the slope of the increasing temperatures.  2) The graph of the Floor function looks like a staircase.  Derive a floor function such that each step starts at a peak of your data and ends at the next peak.  3) Subtract the floor function from the line.  This will give you a saw tooth wave.  4) The absolute value of a saw tooth wave is a triangle wave.

Comment: Thats pretty clear, I've just written the form on this site, it's a lot easier to understand. You guys are lifesavers, thanks! http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/graphs/equations/basic.jsp#c=draw_basicgraphequation&v1=y%3D45*abs(2*((x-1)%2F24-floor((x-1)%2F24%2B0.5)))-10&v2=0&v3=23&v4=-10&v5=45

Answer (score 1):

The data in your table is linear up and down from a peak at hour 13 and a minimum at hour 1. If that is the type of model that you want then this is really easy to put into a formulaic solution. You would just simply perform linear interpolation between the two extremes of the temperature based upon the hour value. You would have two data points:

(xmin, ymin) as (hour-min, temp-min)

(xmax, ymax) as (hour-max, temp-max)

You would have two equations of the form:

[image]

The two equations would use the (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) values as the above two data points but apply them the opposite assignment (ie peak would be (x0, y0) on one and (x1, y1) in the other equation.

You would then select which equation to use based upon the hour value, insert the X value as the hour and compute as Y for the temperature value.

You will want to offset the X values used in the equations so that you take care of the offset between when Hour 0 and where the minimum temperature peak happens.

Comment: This sounds perfect. My maths however, would let me down - I'm a confident programmer, not mathematician. Is there somewhere that explains this to an idiot?

Comment: Is this basically just saying - if the hour is below the peak, lerp between the minimum temp and the maximum temp. If it is above the peak, flip the values around lerp between the maximum temp and the minimum temp?

Comment: @brighterdean - Yes. It is nearly that simple. But you will need to offset the hour to account for the fact that the minimum temp happens at hour 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do this using a simple set of values in the function, if you wish, add these as parameters;

```
    public double GetTemp(double hour)
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = min + 12;

        double lowest = -10;
        double highest = 35;

        double change = 3.75;

        return (hour > max) ? ((max - hour) * change) + highest : (hour < min) ? ((min - hour)*change) + lowest : ((hour - max) * change) + highest;
    }
```

I have tested this according to your example and it is working with 19.75 = 9.6875.

There is no check to see whether the value entered is within 0-24, but that you can probably manage yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use simple 2 point linear approximation. Try somthing like this:

```
    function double hourTemp(double hour)
    {
       idx1 = round(hour); 
       idx2 = idx1 + 1;
       return (data[idx2] - data[idx1]) * (hour - idx1) + data[idx1];
    }
```

1. Or use 3,5 or more points to get polynom cofficients with Ordinary Least Squares method.
2. Your sample data similar to the sin function so you can make sin function approximation.